# Food Poisoning Prevention

Tags: food-safety

How long is it till the chicken spoils 
I'm trying to Prevent Poising my family an others .how long would it be till the chicken is bad,?

Comment: That depends on a *huge* number of factors, including how the chicken was handled, stored, cooked (or not) and in any case it's usually only possible to determine whether the food exceeds an estimated level of risk (usually one set by government agencies). Unfortunately, it's pretty much impossible for anybody (much less us humble folks) to tell you for sure.

Comment: You may want to check out http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat for related information. If those don't address your concern, you'll need to get more specific with your question for us to help.

Comment: This would be topical : http://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2015/02/02/bug-system